# BaseDeleteView throws AttributeError (render_to_response missing)

Tags: django, django-views

I try to implement a view based on BaseDeleteView for a website that acts as a frontend to an REST backend. Both sides communicate over HTTP requests. What I want to achieve is that I send a `GET` request to an activation URI (send per email after registration). Inside this view I first send a HTTP request to a backend, and then delete the activation object from the database of the frontend. I don't want to have a confirmation page, so `DeleteView` is not possible.

```
class ActivationView(BaseDeleteView):
    success_url = "/activation/success/"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        uuid = self.kwargs['uuid']
        try:
            obj = AccountRegistration.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise Http404('Registration not found.')

        return obj

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_obj()

        if obj.expire_date < datetime.now():
            obj.delete()
            raise Http404('Registration expired.')

        # send a http request to the backend
        t = Transaction('/activate/%s/' % obj.account_name)
        t.emit()

        # delete the object
        obj.delete()

        # and redirect the request
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

My `urls.py` looks like that:

```
url(r'^activate/(?P<uuid>\w+)/$',
    ActivationView.as_view(), name="account-activate"),
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/crito/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/thirty-web/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/crito/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/thirty-web/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/crito/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/thirty-web/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/crito/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/thirty-web/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 203, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/home/crito/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/thirty-web/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/crito/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/thirty-web/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 47, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/crito/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/thirty-web/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/crito/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.2/thirty-web/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 100, in get
    return self.render_to_response(context)
AttributeError: 'ActivationView' object has no attribute 'render_to_response'
```

In my eyes it shouldn't even call render_to_response. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to leave out the confirmation page, just call your DeleteView directly with POST. This is most desirable as the deletion of an object should be protected by csrf.

Answer (score 0):

You've inherited from `BaseDeleteView`, which as [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#deleteview) states, doesn't include the `TemplateResponseMixin` - ie all the bits that are to do with rendering a response.

Inherit from `DeleteView` instead.

Comment: But if I inherit from ``DeleteView`` I have to confirm the deletion in a seperate page. I really don't wan't this. What I want is to send a ``GET`` request to the URI and that this executes the deletion. I then redirect to a different URI.