# Why is BaseDeleteView is throwing an Attribute error saying object has no attribute render_to_response?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to implement BaseDeleteview, but getting this erroe message -> 'DeletePostView' object has no attribute 'render_to_response', I did not use DeleteView mainly beacuse it expects a confirmation template and I am using bootraps's modal (like a pop up)  for confirmation.

I have found much similar question here -> [BaseDeleteView throws AttributeError (render_to_response missing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664662/basedeleteview-throws-attributeerror-render-to-response-missing)

```
class DeletePostView(SuccessMessageMixin, BaseDeleteView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'remove_post_confirm_object'
    # template_name = "posts/delete_confirm_post.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:profile')
    success_message = 'Post has been deleted SuccessFully!'
```

Error Tranceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gaurav/Programming_Practice/DjangoProjects/Blog/blog-project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/gaurav/Programming_Practice/DjangoProjects/Blog/blog-project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/gaurav/Programming_Practice/DjangoProjects/Blog/blog-project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/gaurav/Programming_Practice/DjangoProjects/Blog/blog-project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gaurav/Programming_Practice/DjangoProjects/Blog/blog-project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gaurav/Programming_Practice/DjangoProjects/Blog/blog-project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gaurav/Programming_Practice/DjangoProjects/Blog/blog-project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gaurav/Programming_Practice/DjangoProjects/Blog/blog-project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 108, in get
    return self.render_to_response(context)
 
Exception Type: AttributeError at /post/2020/10/10/wertyuio/remove
Exception Value: 'DeletePostView' object has no attribute 'render_to_response'
```

Comment: Are you POSTing or GETing the deletion endpoint?

Comment: It's a get request @iri

Answer (score 0):

Because `BaseDeleteView` has a `get` method which in it's body another method named `self.render_to_response(context)` will be called. This method will came from a builtin mixin named `TemplateResponseMixin` and since you used `BaseDeleteView` this method does not exist and it will raise an error. So you should override `get` method of your view from this:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

to something like this one or any type that you need:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# override get method of your DeletePostView
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context=context)
```

Or you can add `SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin` (i.e. `from django.views.generic import SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin`) in your `DeletePostView` parents to add this functionality to your view and override any method to customize it (which will be the same as `DeleteView`).

Comment: Yes, you are right, but my goal was to **avoid that confirmation template** which ultimately gets called no matter which approach I use. So, used **kind of trick** to avoid the template.   Basically, in the template I created a form with only button as its attribute and I called DeletePostView with POST request. This solved my issue.                                                                       PS. And, I inherited DeletePostView from DeleteView instead.